# How do I lookup using 2 values, Verticle and Horizonal? (Apple Numbers)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, iwork-numbers

I have a sheet that has an individuals info, one table as their Age (TABLE 1). Another Table has a score in cell (TABLE 2). I want to lookup the VALUE that corresponds with their age and score in another Table (TABLE 3) return in to the cell along (CELL F27).

Would I use a combination of VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP or INDEX.... either way I'm at a loss at to what I should use and how to use it.

Table 1
AGE: 26 (CELL E2)

Table 2
SCORE: 15 (CELL E27) (VALUE NEEDED in CELL F27, NEEDING FORMULA to retrieve the value "33")

TABLE 3
AGE        |24|25|26|

Scores: 10 |40|39|38|
        11 |41|40|37|
        12 |42|41|36|
        13 |43|42|35|
        14 |44|43|34|
        15 |45|44|33|
        16 |46|45|32|
        17 |47|46|31|

Comment: You want answers for both excel 2007, excel 2010 and iwork ?

Answer (score 1):

BINGO!
[Answered](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/2d_lookup.php)

We have an answer, in this simple tutorial for morond like me oh yes!